# Django form choices loaded from database are not updated

Tags: django, django-forms

I got a form which I use for listing customers from my Database.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):

customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=True, label='Customer')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['customer'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(addcustomer.company_name + ';' + addcustomer.address + ';' + addcustomer.country + ';' + addcustomer.zip + ';' + addcustomer.state_province + ';' + addcustomer.city,
                                                          addcustomer.company_name + ' ' + addcustomer.address + ' ' + addcustomer.country + ' ' + addcustomer.zip + ' ' + addcustomer.state_province + ' ' + addcustomer.city) for addcustomer in customers])
```

Next I got a modal window with an "add customer" form inside.

Problem:
When I insert a new customer via the modal form into the Database (which is in fact working), it won't be in the choices for the CustomerForm until I restart the local server.

I need a way to update the list asap after adding a customer.
Tried with the `__init__` method but no luck..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't show where `customers` is defined. Move that line inside the `__init__` method, so that it is fetched when the form is initialised, not when the server starts.

```
class CustomerForm(forms.Form):
    customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[], required=True, label='Customer')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        customers = Customer.objects.all()  # move this line inside __init__!
        self.fields['customer'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[<snip code that uses customers>])
```